# Confusion in creating table design

Tags: mysql, schema

I am using Mysql and I have two tables-

```
BusDetails
    +-------+-----------+
    | busId | BusName   |
    +-------+-----------+
    | 1     | A TRAVELS |
    | 2     | B TRAVELS |
    | 3     | C TRAVELS |
    +-------+-----------+

AreaDetails
+--------+----------+
| cityId | cityName |
+--------+----------+
| 1      | ABC      |
| 2      | DEF      |
| 3      | GHI      |
| 4      | JKL      |
+--------+----------+
```

Now I have to create third table which will map bus table to city table. Suppose busId 1 stops at cityId 2 and 3 and bustId 2 stops at cityId 1 and 4. To create this scenario I have 2 options-

```
first option-
+-------+--------+
| busId | areaId |
+-------+--------+
| 1     | 3,2    |
| 2     | 4,1    |
+-------+--------+

second option-
+-------+--------+
| busId | areaId |
+-------+--------+
| 1     | 2      |
| 1     | 3      |
| 2     | 1      |
| 2     | 4      |
+-------+--------+
```

In future when there will be large number of records then which table will give better performance and why ?

Comment: I think second option is batter. As you will be manage one to many relationship in this scenario.so you can easily find out any information related to bus or area.

Comment: Learn about database normalization. Comma-separated lists are evil in relational databases.

Comment: @Barmar then what about redundancy ? I am repeating busId again and again If I go with second option.

Comment: It's not redundant if each one is describing an independent relationship. It would be redundant if you also had `busName` in the mapping table.

Comment: this is the difference between the **relational** database model and **hierarchical** and **network** models. When an you have a many-to-many relationship, you have to list all the pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is poor because comma-separated lists do not get indexed. If you want to find all the busses in area 2, you would have to use

```
SELECT busID
FROM bus_areas
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', areaID)
```

This will have to perform a full table scan, parse the `areaID` column on each row, and test whether `2` is a member of the resulting array.

With the second version you can do:

```
SELECT busID
FROM bus_areas
WHERE areaID = 2
```

If you have an index on `areaID`, this will be extremely efficient.

If you wanted to know how many busses are in each area, it's easy with the second option:

```
SELECT areaID, COUNT(*)
FROM bus_areas
GROUP BY areaID
```

With the first option it would be more cumbersome:

```
SELECT cityID, COUNT(*)
FROM areaDetails a
JOIN bus_areas ba ON FIND_IN_SET(a.cityID, ba.areaID)
GROUP BY cityID
```

This will be very inefficient because it has to perform M*N `FIND_IN_SET` operations, and as I explained above this cannot be indexed. Notice that I had to join with the `areaDetails` table because there's no way to enumerate all the areas in the comma-separated lists in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends upon your use.

Although first option is not recommended but if you have very large data and you are not planning to perform wide range of Database operations (probably for self or small project) you can use it.

Second options has it's own advantage and recommended by relational model. It will give you more flexibility and scalability as this minimize redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Second Table Is Better For All Reason Baecause At long time you have big data second type in save so many rows but better for getting report easy in easy for SQL query easy. you can all type join easy.